# Is there a good *strict* date parser for Java?

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, strict

Is there a good, *strict* date parser for Java?  I have access to Joda-Time but I have yet to see this option.  I found the "Is there a good date parser for Java" question, and while this is related it is sort of the opposite.  Whereas that question was asking for a lenient, more fuzzy-logic and prone to human error parser, I would like a strict parser.  For example, with both JodaTime (as far as I can tell) and simpleDateFormat, if you have a format "MM/dd/yyyy":

parse this: 40/40/4353

This becomes a valid date.  I want a parser that knows that 40 is an invalid month and date.  Surely some implementation of this exists in Java?

Comment: Really? The year is certainly valid, but as for the day and moth, it is not. I have to see that. If I remember well the extra months will be added to the year, isn't?

Comment: Apparently it does this, it just started working.  I lack the power to close this question, however.

Comment: Joda time will be added to Java SE finally. This is featured in the front page  ( http://java.sun.com/javase/ ): JSR 310: A New Java Date/Time API. It says it is "..mainly based on the Joda Time API" ( http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2008/09/18/jsr-310-new-java-date-time-api.html)

Comment: @Metroid: About closing. I guess marking the answer as accepted will be enough.

Comment: @Oscar: I simply didn't see the close link until close (1) appeared.  My mistake.

Comment: Re: Joda making into Java SE
It sounds like it may not make it into Java 7. 
https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/servlets/ReadMsg?list=dev&msgNo=1389

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I don't see that [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) recognizes that as a valid date. Example:

```
strict = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")
try {
    strict.parseDateTime('40/40/4353')
    assert false
} catch (org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException e) {
    assert 'Cannot parse "40/40/4353": Value 40 for monthOfYear must be in the range [1,12]' == e.message
}
```

As best as I can tell, neither does [DateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html) with [setLenient(false)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient(boolean)). Example:

```
try {
    df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('MM/dd/yyyy')
    df.setLenient(false)
    df.parse('40/40/4353')
    assert false
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
    assert e.message =~ 'Unparseable'
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which version of JodaTime are you using?

Comment: 1.6 certainly exhibits this behaviour.

Comment: That's really odd.  I had a test that was failing, but for some reason it works now and I get that exception you mentioned.  Very strange.  Joda time it is, then! :)

Comment: That's good to know about DateFormat (there's so much there it's hard to find the particular method you're looking for), but I like JodaTime because it doesn't have any synchronization issues with a formatter instance.  It's a real gotcha with DateFormat.

Answer (score 11):

A good way to do strict validation with DateFormat is re-formatting the parsed date and checking equality to the original string:

```
String myDateString = "87/88/9999";
Date myDate = dateFormat.parse(myDateString);
if (!myDateString.equals(df.format(myDate))){
  throw new ParseException();
}
```

Works like  a charm.

Comment: How does it handle if e.g. dates or months are entered without a leading zero which the rendering adds?

Comment: If the rendering is done by the Formatter (like it should), then there is absolutely no problem. If you create an external rendering formatter, your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `apache.commons.validator.routines.DateValidator` to validate the date,if you do not want to use `SimpleDateFormat`.

Example :

```
 public static Date validateDate(String value, String pattern) {
       DateValidator validator = new DateValidator();
       Date date = null;
           if (pattern!=null) {    //Pattern is passed
               date = validator.validate(value, pattern);
           } else {
               date = validator.validate(value);
           }
       return date;
    }
```

So if a **null is returned** it means that the date is not valid otherwise it's a valid date.This method is an alternative to using the `SimpleDateFormat` as you don't have to rely on exception being thrown to identify if it's a valid date or not.