# How can I make Joda DateTime parser to only accept strings of form yyyyMMdd?

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime

I would like to use Joda-Time to parse dates in the format yyyyMMdd (so the date should have eight digits). I defined my date formatter as follows

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyyMMdd").withZoneUTC();

// a valid eight-digit date
String dateValid = "20130814";
DateTime dateJoda = formatter.parseDateTime(dateValid);
System.out.println(dateJoda.toString());

// an invalid seven digit date
String dateInvalid = "2013081";
dateJoda = formatter.parseDateTime(dateInvalid);
System.out.println(dateJoda.toString());
```

I expected to see an exception when parsing the second invalid date. However the output of the code is

```
2013-08-14T00:00:00.000Z
2013-08-01T00:00:00.000Z
```

Why does the Joda parser accept the invalid date with only 7 digits? How do I have to change my formatter to  not accept any dates which don't have exactly 8 digits?

Comment: Good parse you have. Wrong is format you do. (Yoda Master:)

Comment: It seems that joda time is not so strict with parsing. Is this post helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489538/is-there-a-good-strict-date-parser-for-java

Comment: @vikingsteve Actually not so much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only option I know of is to create your own DateTimeFormatter using [DateTimeFormatterBuilder](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendDayOfMonth%28int%29) and use fixed decimals for each field.

In your case it would be:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    .appendFixedDecimal(DateTimeFieldType.year(),4)
    .appendFixedDecimal(DateTimeFieldType.monthOfYear(),2)
    .appendFixedDecimal(DateTimeFieldType.dayOfMonth(),2)
    .toFormatter()
    .withZoneUTC();
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work. But don't forget `.withZoneUTC()`

Comment: I found another solution: `DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.basicDate().withZoneUTC();` . It works, because the ISO basic date is equal to yyyyMMdd . But this is in general less flexible than constructing a formatter using `.appendFixedDecimal()`.

Comment: @soulcheck worth appending asmaiers suggestion to your answer?