# Strict parsing date time in groovy without using static objects

Tags: datetime, groovy, jodatime, strict, exact-match

I'm trying to parse a date time object in Groovy running on Java 7 with strict/exact parsing.

I've tried using `SimpleDateFormat` with `setLenient` set to `false` but it is still too lenient, e.g. parsing value `2018-8-2` with format `yyyy-MM-dd` still succeeds (and returns the wrong date).

I came across a potential answer here:
[Java: How to parse a date strictly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088140/java-how-to-parse-a-date-strictly)

However the environment I'm working on does not allow me to invoke static methods for security reasons, preventing me from using Joda's

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Given this restriction, how can I do an exact/strict parse of a DateTime string in Groovy?

Comment: Do you mean `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `DateTimeFormatterBuilder` from Joda-Time ([here](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/index.html)), with a simple regex to broadly confirm the format. (There is a better way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18489660/12704) but it uses static methods.)

Full example [here](https://github.com/codetojoy/easter_eggs_for_groovy/tree/master/egg_36_stack_overflow_51620520).

Consider:

```
def getDateTime(def s) {
    def result = null

    def regex = /^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$/

    if (s ==~ regex) {
        // yyyy-MM-dd
        def formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                             .appendYear(4,4)
                             .appendLiteral('-')
                             .appendMonthOfYear(2)
                             .appendLiteral('-')
                             .appendDayOfMonth(2)
                             .toFormatter()
        try {
            result = formatter.parseDateTime(s)
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // System.err.println "TRACER ex: " + ex.message
        }
    }

    return result
}
```

Usage:

```
assert new DateTime(2018,8,2,0,0) == getDateTime('2018-08-02')
assert null == getDateTime('18-08-02')
assert null == getDateTime('2018-8-02')
assert null == getDateTime('2018-08-2')
```