# Groovy/Grails Date.parse

Tags: grails, groovy

It would seem to me that the following Groovy Script should fail with parsing exceptions:

```
println Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss","2014-10-06T05:58:00-0500")
println Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss","2014-14-06T05:58:00-0500")
println Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss","2014-10-45T05:58:00-0500")
println Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss","2014-10-06T35:58:00-0500")
println Date.parse("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss","2014-10-06T05:95:00-0500")
```

Note that:

- the second date has an invalid month
- the third date has an invalid day
- the fourth date has an invalid hour
- the fifth date has invalid minutes

I'm pretty sure that I know what it is actually doing, but it is not what I expect to happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written in the [docs](http://beta.groovy-lang.org/docs/latest/html/groovy-jdk/) `parse` is just a wrapper around `SimpleDateFormat`. It is possible to unset `SimpleDateFormat` lenient as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489538/is-there-a-good-strict-date-parser-for-java/489574#489574) answer however I suppose it's not possible to it when invoking just `Date.parse`. So to get *correct* results You should use a strict `SimpleDateFormat`.